# WinSock Bluetooth API in C on WINDOWS ws2bth.h not found

Tags: c, windows, sockets, bluetooth

I know there are a lot of tutorials on how to implement a winsock bluetooth socket, but they are all very confusing. One says it's not possible in `Code:Blocks`, others say you have to download another full Windows API of about 300MB again and others are in different languages like c# or c++ or only for Linux.

I have installed `Code:Blocks` and I'm relatively new to it. I already included the `ws2_32.lib` and now I want to create a bluetooth socket but code:blocks tells me `file not found`. I'm working on windows and have to add windows stuff again and again. Please can anyone tell me how I get a WinSock Bluetooth Socket on Windows (NOT LINUX please) to work? I use this code:

ps: i also tried `#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` without 1
pps: i found someone saying you cant use VC compiled libs with MinGW but how can i use bluetooth sockets then?

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN 1 // Don't include Winsock v1

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#include <windows.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#include <winsock2.h>

#include <ws2bth.h>

#include <BluetoothAPIs.h>

#define SDP_RECORD_SIZE   0x0000004f

#define SDP_CHANNEL_OFFSET 32

struct

{

            BTHNS_SETBLOB   b;

            unsigned char   uca[SDP_RECORD_SIZE];

} bigBlob;



BOOL BT_SetService()

{

   ULONG recordHandle = 0;

   ULONG ulSdpVersion = BTH_SDP_VERSION;

   BLOB blob;

   WSAQUERYSET Service;



   // Bluetooth device profile sample

   BYTE rgbSdpRecord[] = {

         0x35, 0x4d, 0x09, 0x00, 0x01, 0x35, 0x11, 0x1c,

         0x29, 0xf9, 0xc0, 0xfd, 0xbb, 0x6e, 0x47, 0x97,

         0x9f, 0xa9, 0x3e, 0xc9, 0xa8, 0x54, 0x29, 0x0c,

         0x09, 0x00, 0x04, 0x35, 0x0c, 0x35, 0x03, 0x19,

         0x01, 0x00, 0x35, 0x05, 0x19, 0x00, 0x03, 0x08,

         0x1a, 0x09, 0x00, 0x06, 0x35, 0x09, 0x09, 0x65,

         0x6e, 0x09, 0x00, 0x6a, 0x09, 0x01, 0x00, 0x09,

         0x00, 0x09, 0x35, 0x08, 0x35, 0x06, 0x19, 0x11,

         0x05, 0x09, 0x01, 0x00, 0x09, 0x01, 0x00, 0x25,

         0x06, 0x53, 0x65, 0x72, 0x69, 0x61, 0x6c

   };



   bigBlob.b.pRecordHandle   = (HANDLE *)&recordHandle;

   bigBlob.b.pSdpVersion     = &ulSdpVersion;

   // bigBlob.b.fSecurity       = 0;

   // bigBlob.b.fOptions        = 0;

   bigBlob.b.ulRecordLength  = SDP_RECORD_SIZE;

   memcpy (bigBlob.b.pRecord, rgbSdpRecord, SDP_RECORD_SIZE);



   blob.cbSize    = sizeof(BTHNS_SETBLOB) + SDP_RECORD_SIZE - 1;

   blob.pBlobData = (PBYTE) &bigBlob;



   memset (&Service, 0, sizeof(Service));

   Service.dwSize = sizeof(Service);

   Service.lpBlob = &blob;

   Service.dwNameSpace = NS_BTH;



   if (WSASetService(&Service,RNRSERVICE_REGISTER,0) == SOCKET_ERROR)

   {

      printf("WSASetService() failed with error code %d\n", WSAGetLastError ());

      return FALSE;

   }

   else

   {

       printf("WSASetService() is working!\n");

       return TRUE;

   }

}



int main(int argc, char **argv)

{

            WSADATA wsd;

            BOOL RetVal;



            if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsd) != 0)

            {

                        printf("Unable to load Winsock! Error code is %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

                        return 1;

            }

            else

                        printf("WSAStartup() is OK, Winsock lib loaded!\n");



            RetVal = BT_SetService();



            printf("The return value is: %d\n", RetVal);



            if(WSACleanup() == 0)

                        printf("WSACleanup() is OK!\n");

            else

                        printf("WSACleanup() failed miserably with error code %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

            return 0;

}
```